# How do online java compilers work?

Tags: java, jvm

I am building online compiler website.
To execute a program in local system where we know the file name and class name.
eg: **MyProgram.java**

```
class MyProgram{
    public static void main(String[] args){
         System.out.println("Myprogram in local");//
    }
}
$ javac MyProgram.java
$ java MyProgram
```

but in online compiler user can have any class name
eg : **MyProgram.java**//this can be whatever defined by admin

```
class UserProgram{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("users program");
    }
}

$ javac MyProgram.java  
$ java somethingthatidontknow //how do i get "users program" outpout ?
```

Comment: Do you only want to compile the code, or also run it? The compiler does not care about the main class. (A compiler is also a lot safer to host than something that executes untrusted code, make sure you have a proper sandbox in place)

Comment: i want to compile and run user's code but not sure how this is going to work

Comment: You can use reflection on the compiled code or parse the java file. The source file name is not required to have the same name as the class.

Comment: Let the user choose which class they want to run.  Give them a choice of everything they've compiled that has a method called `public static void main(String[] args)`.

Comment: do you want java -> jvm bytecode or java -> assembly? or do you actually want to execute the program instead of the compiler output?

Comment: @the8472 i don't want any bytecode all i want is output of user's program

Comment: You can use a javaScript JVM which will run on the client side, but it has big footprint: http://plasma-umass.github.io/doppio-demo/

Answer (score 1):

The name of the class only has to be the same as that of the file if the class is public. So if the user does not declare the class as public, the code will compile fine no matter the name of the file.

So then all you have to do is find out which of the created .class files contains the `main` method. One way to do that would be to invoke `javap` on each class file and grep the output for `static void main`.

Note that when a class *is* declared public, that's a problem for most (all?) existing online IDEs. For example Ideone requires you to name your class `Main` if you make it public.